# How to increase the composite revision of SOA composite while deploying

Tags: python, oracle, weblogic

Firstly deploying the SOA using the command

```
sca_deployComposite(serverUrl,sarLocation,forceDefault=True,user=user,password=password)
```

Then getting the revision number

```
revision=sca_getDefaultCompositeRevision(ipAddress,port,"weblogic","weblogic1",applicationName)
```

Output `1.0`
But how to increase the revision number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revision number from an SCA is set at package time and not at deploy time. If you are using WLST, you can use the package command to set the revision number:

```
sca_package(compositeDir, compositeName, revision, [appHome], [oracleHome])
```